# plot counts with intervals in x axis using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
c1 <- c("p2","p3","p1","p2","p1","p3","p4","p4","p4","p1","p1","p2","p2","p3","p4","p2","p1","p4","p3","p3")
c2 <- c(41,146,79,107,131,127,32,88,119,148,32,65,36,23,44,76,100,98,121,104)

df <- data.frame(c1=c1, c2=c2)
```

I'm trying to create a stacked bar plot in ggplot2 with intervals in the x axis and counts in the y axis

Conceptually something like this

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=c2.intervals, y=count.c2.occurrences, fill=c1)) + geom_bar()
```

in which `c2.intervals` could be `0-70, 71-100, 100-150`

For example, for the interval `0-70`, `p1` appears once, `p2` 3 times, `p3` once and `p4` twice. These would be the counts for the first stacked column in the plot.

What is the best way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cut()` to define your intervals. Also, based on your description, I assume you want `fill = c1` rather than `fill = c2`?

See if the following serves your purpose:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(c2.intervals = cut(c2, breaks = c(0, 70, 100, 150))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = c2.intervals, fill = c1)) +
  geom_bar()
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks @Z.Lin, that's exactly what I was looking for!